# Round robin - dynamic weights

Tags: algorithm, networking, distributed-computing, distributed-system, round-robin

Let's consider a system of N servers, each with some weight w. There are already algorithms like [this one](http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/Weighted_Round-Robin_Scheduling), which describes how to achieve a weighted round-robin policy.

This, however, works, when weights are static and predefined. The problem I am facing is the system, where the Servers periodically (at random time points, independently) update client with their capacity.

Does anyone know a better approach than a simple extension of the weighted approach with **snapshots** i.e. client periodically recalculates weights and runs the algorithm as descibed in the article?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a few load-balancing techniques for a compute grid framework, which are [documented here](https://www.jppf.org/doc/6.1/index.php?title=Built-in_algorithms). The approaches described there are more pragmatic than theoretical, thus they may not fully answer your question, however they should bring an element of answer and hopefully spark some inspiration.

The described techniques are expressed in terms of "how many tasks in a job should be distributed to a given compute node?", which can relatively easily be translated into "what is the probability to assign a task/request to a given node/server?"

Some of these techniques are equivalent to statically weighted round-robin, others dynamically compute the weights based on observable performance data (via continuous feedback), using either deterministic computations or approaches based on AI techniques such as simulated annealing or reinforcement learning.